# How to correctly parititon a drive after a gddrescue with different physical sector size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, bad-sectors, ddrescue

Alright so I have been thinking about upgrading to an SSD for a while now, since my HDD was old as hell and was already getting some uncorrectable sectors as the replacement sectors were already filled up. This led to some unexpected freezes of my Win7 installation so i thought it was time to move on.

So I went ahead and after some research I got the Crucial MX500 1TB, an upgrade from my previous Seagate Momentus 7200.4 500GB
I didn't want to redo all the partitioning and installing of the hundreds of programs I have installed and I don't like copying file-by-file since I've had problem with that in the past if I encountered a bad sector.
So I did ddrescue(gddrecue) on the thing like this:

```
ddrescue -r3 -vvvv -d --force /dev/sdc /dev/sdb /root/rescuehhd.log
```

It completed after 8h with 9 bad areas, 72 read errors which is higher than the in total 63 reported bad sectors by SMART but whatever, i knew this was happening and the drive still worked.
I went ahead and looked at the partition table and gparted immediately told me "Can't have a partition outside the disk"

Long story short, I find out the new SSD has a logical/physical sector size of 4096/4096 and my old has 512/512, so now all partition sizes are exact multiples of 8 but the drive is only twice as big.

My question is, can I somehow either:

- correct the partition table and pray that it
  works or
- redo the clone, put more stress on the failing drive (yay,
  while copying from sector to sector and therefore have my data
  horribly misaligned but working or
- find another way that magically solves all my problems :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved after rerunning gddrescue, there must have been an error in the sector data, as the drive no longer returns 4096/4096 as sector size.